# Line Integral along a straight line.

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Can you help me with this question?
The value of the integral of the function $g(x,y)=4x^3+10y^4$ along the straight line segment from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(1,2)$ in the $xy$-plane is?

My answer is coming $33\sqrt 5$.
The correct answer is being shown as $33$ only. 
Need help?????

Comment: If you tell us, how exactly did you get your answer, we will be able to find the exact place where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. If $\gamma(t)=(t,2t)$, then that line integral is equal to$$\int_0^1g\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\bigl\lVert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rVert\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^1(4t^3+160t^4)\sqrt5\,\mathrm dt=33\sqrt5.$$